# "I was out shopping this afternoon." / "I went shopping this afternoon." / "I was shopping this afternoon."

Tags: meaning-in-context

In my English content dictionary I saw the sentence:

> I was out shopping this afternoon.

Could you please explain the difference between the mentioned sentence and

> I went shopping this afternoon.

?

I don't understand what's the matter to say "be out" in that context. I think it's obviously that shops isn't at your place and you're out.

Can I say:

> I was shopping this afternoon.

instead of

> I was out shopping this afternoon.

?
If I can, what's the difference in usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no great difference.

*I went shopping* states that you left the house for that purpose. But if a friend came to your house and found no-one at home, you might explain later that it was because you *were out shopping.* Of course you could just say "I was shopping", - *out* just emphasises the fact that you were away from home.